# Computing the index of fixed point for the system of equations $x'=x^2$ and $y'=-y$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Consider the system of equations $$x' = x^2$$ $$y'=-y.$$ Compute the index of fixed point at the origin both visually and computationally, or just write down the integral.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ To find the fixed point, integrate both equations $$\int f'(x) = \int x^2 dx \text{ and } \int f'(y) = \int -y dy.$$ Therefore, $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + C \text{ and } f(y) = -\frac{y^2}{2} + C.$ Next, to find the fixed point index, let $x=0, \text{ and } y=0$ so $f(0) = C.$ Therefore, $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + 0$ and $f(y) =-\frac{y^2}{2} + 0.$ So the fixed point of $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y) = 0.$

So the index for the first function is $I(f(x),x_0) = (\frac{x^3}{3}, 0)$ and for our second function it is $I(f(y),y_0) = (-\frac{y^2}{2},0).$ Can someone please help me complete the problem?

Comment: You already know the fixed point (no need for any computations in this respect), now you need to draw the phase portrait and obtain the index from there. Then you need to look at the vector field $$\frac{-y(2x,0)-x^2(0,-1)}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{(-2xy,x^2)}{x^4+y^2}$$ (that's the usual prescription but it depends on what you have learned so you should start something first).

Comment: @Aryadeva Sure, any **good** book on ODE's discussing this elementary part of index theory. For example, take the best of them all: Coddington and Levinson.

Comment: Thank you John @JohnB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get fixed points, we need $x'=0$ and $y'=0$. So, the fixed points are $x^2 = 0$ and $-y=0$ so $x=0$ and $y=0$. Thus, $(0,0)$ is a fixed point.

Let $f=x^2$ and $g=-y$, then $f_x = 2x, f_y=0, g_x = 0,$ and $g_y=-1.$ Therefore the Jacobian is $$J = \begin{pmatrix} f_x & g_x \\ f_y & g_y \end{pmatrix}$$ $$J_{(0,0)} = \begin{pmatrix} 2x & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}_{(0,0)} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues at $(0,0)$ are $|J-I\lambda| = 0.$ $$\begin{pmatrix} 0-\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & -1-\lambda \end{pmatrix} = 0 \text{ so } \lambda = 0, -1.$$ The system is marginally stable if it has one or more distinct poles on the imaginary axis and any remaining poles have negative real part.

Now, taking the integrals, $x' = x^2, \frac{dx}{x^2} = dt$ $$\implies \int x^{-2}dx = t + C$$ $$\implies -\frac{1}{x} = t + C.$$ Now, $y' = -y , \frac{dy}{dt} = -y \implies \frac{dy}{y} = \int -dt = \log y = -t + \log C$. So, $\frac{y}{C} = e^{-t}$ and $y= Ce^{-t}.$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You cant treat function as variable. Solving then this system of equations would look completely different. Treat these functions like functions dependable from paramter t.
Thus, as a simple differentional equation solving we get:
$.\\y(t)=C*e^{-t} \\ x(t)=-\frac{1}{t}+C $

I don't know what do to furhter, but hope this will help a bit.

Comment: Yes it does help, thank you Michal for your help!

Comment: The solution for $x'=x^2$ is wrong.